# How do you describe a behavior or demonstration that is pointless but is performed for effect, habit, or expectation?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

What word best describes a behavior or demonstration that is pointless but is performed for effect, habit, or expectation?

That is, how do you refer to or describe something that is purely ritualistic, but completely inconsequential and needless? It's only being done because it's been done in the past.

Comment: Welcome, Mike.  Could you please say more about what you are looking for?  A behaviour that is performed for effect or from some kind of expectation does have a point.  It would help you obtain the kind of answer you need of you gave three examples of what you are talking about:  one of something done for effect, one out of habit and one for expectation.  At the same, I am not at all clear what you mean by "for ... expectation".

Comment: "Ritual" or "ritualistic" sounds fine. But it's going to depend whether it's something trivial like tipping your hat, saying please and thank you, or something more serious like following your father into the armed forces or committing ritual suicide. Something grand, like a church wedding, or something minor, like ensuring your trouser fly is closed.

Answer (score 3):

One such word is **formality**. [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/formality) has

> **formality** *noun*
> something that has to be done but has no real importance

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/formality) has

> **formality** *noun*
> **3** : an established form or procedure that is required or conventional

For example

> Now that the formalities are over, we can get down to business.

Comment: Likewise, the adjective here would be *pro forma*

Answer (score 2):

Such actions could be described as *perfunctory*. [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/perfunctory) says that a perfunctory action is:

> characterized by routine or superficiality : MECHANICAL

These actions could also be described more neutrally/habitually as being *ritual*, as in a *ritual demonstration*. Per [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ritual),

> done in accordance with social custom or normal protocol

Note that these are both adjectives, and you seem to be looking for a noun. Still, I just thought I'd put these out there since they're pretty closely related.

Comment: A comment under *my* answer suggests the opposite: an unclear question.

Comment: This word failed my memory as I was writing my answer.

Answer (score 0):

a tradition or traditonal
1
a
: an inherited, established, or customary pattern of thought, action, or behavior (such as a religious practice or a social custom)
b
: a belief or story or a body of beliefs or stories relating to the past that are commonly accepted as historical though not verifiable

2
: the handing down of information, beliefs, and customs by word of mouth or by example from one generation to another without written instruction

3
: cultural continuity in social attitudes, customs, and institutions

4
: characteristic manner, method, or style

Comment: You should include the source of the definition.

Answer (score -2):

**Sanctimonial** ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sanctimonial)) Making a show of being morally better than others, especially hypocritically pious.

**Preachy**  ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/preachy))  Tending toward excessive moralization.